# Error removing initramfs tools (fresh install)

Tags: installation, 13.10

I have seen a few other people with this issue, but they have an existing install that they can drop into to fix it. I don't!

So, I am trying to install Xubuntu 13.10 using a live USB, and in doing so I have intentionally formatted the installation partitions (all my data is safely floating in the sky). Everything seems to work until right at the very end I get the message:

```
Error removing initramfs-tools:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

The only thing I can think of is that some partition somewhere isn't big enough... I have:

```
sda1 /swap   512MB
sda2 /boot   56MB
sda3 /home   32GB
sda5 /var    4GB
sda6 /opt    4GB
sda7 /       31GB
```

Any advice at all would be welcome as at the moment I have a totally unbootable system following the attempted install. Booting to GUI hangs at the splash screen. Trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> from there does NOT give a login prompt. Booting into recovery and dropping to root shell leaves me with no partition other than sda7 and sda5 mounted, all the other partitions refuse to mount!

If I attempt to mount, for example sda2 then:

```
# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /boot
mount: /dev/sda2 already mounted or /boot busy
```

**Edit:** Now cross-posted to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2198405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I 'solved' this by installing 12.04.3 LTS instead of 13.10.  As part of this I also 'rejigged' my partitioning schema:

```
sda1 /swap  swap 4GB
sda2 /boot  ext4 128MB
sda3 /var   ext4 8GB
sda5 /opt   ext4 4GB
sda6 /      ext4 16GB
sda7             16GB
sda8 /home  ext4 200GB
```

sda7 is unformatted free space for test installations and is where I will eventually try installing 13.10.

In any case, 12.04.3 LTS is installed and running quite happily.

Answer (score -1):

Instead  of dropping into a root shell please enter dpkg or fsck or grub options from the menu and wait till it finishes. This will automatically mount the file-systems. Also enable network before dropping into root shell. Otherwise you wont be able to download the package list or any packages:

[image]

Please try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you still end up with the same error, try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Hi - do you mean from the recovery/root console?

Comment: This will *at least* need some instructions to mount the drives read/writeable before this can possibly work. Please add the information. "sudo dpkg -i" defiantly doesn't apply to this problem.

Comment: Thanks, using fsck gets the drives mounted, but the network won't start.  Unfortunately the errors are too fast to see!  I get "Warning: Fake intictl called, doing nothing" if I try a manual "service networking start" from the root console.  The apt-get commands all fail with no network.

Comment: I'm going to try the LTS release and see if that's any better...